# Store GUID correctly as UUID in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, uuid, guid

I generate a GUID in C# and store it in a SQL Server dable as UUID as follows (the GUID is UUID type):

```
string guid = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
                        
using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.settings(GUID) VALUES('" + guid + "');"
```

Now I have two questions:

- I thought guids can be stored directly into a database without casting them to strings
- The saved Guid is all uppercase in the SQL Server database

I read that I have convert the guid to a byte-array to store as UUID in the database. I can't get it work without the string-parsing, but I want to do it correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is stored as a 16-byte binary value. It is not stored as a string in upper case or lower case. This is just how it is represented when selected

Comment: T-SQL has no native literal syntax for `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, so you do need to pass them as string literals if you're interpolating them into the query -- which of course you *should not do*, as that's what parameters are for. Say no to SQL injection. `INSERT INTO dbo.Settings(GUID) VALUES (@Guid)`, and then you won't need to pass a string.

Comment: An advice, use Parameters, you can read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So i don't use injection in General? Is this more professional?